# How do I center multiple divs along bottom of canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

So I've been playing around with my code for some time now, and I still am 
not able to get the div elements to properly center themselves along the bottom of my canvas element. The code I have so far gets me relatively close, but it is not quite there. I've posted the relative css snippets below, if anyone can give me some direction I would be really appreciative.

```
#shapeCanvas {
width:800px;
height:650px;
border:1px solid #000000;
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.styleDiv {
color:#FFFFFF;
font-family:"Verdana";
background-color:#36648b;
border:2px solid #000000;
border-radius:5px;
padding:5px;
display:inline-block;
width:150px;
height:25px;
}
```

Comment: Try adding **text-align:center** to #shapeCanvas css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a container div, also `inline-block`, and give it `text-align: center`. This will make sure all your `inline-block` divs are anchored at the center of the page.

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#shapeCanvas {
  width:800px;
  height:650px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styleDiv {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-family:"Verdana";
  background-color:#36648b;
  border:2px solid #000000;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
  height:25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="shapeCanvas"></div>
  <div class="styleDiv"></div>
  <div class="styleDiv"></div>
  <div class="styleDiv"></div>
</div>
```